# Getting Java IO exception when using jenkins cli , jdk 8.144 , jenkins v2.93

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

This is the error.

> root@myserver#java -jar
>   /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s
>   http://localhost:8181 -auth ****:**** help
>
> ```
> java.io.IOException: Bogus chunk size
> at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.processRaw(ChunkedInputStream.java:319)
> at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:572)
> at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:609)
> at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:696)
> at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3375)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3368)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3356)
> at hudson.cli.CLI$1ClientSideImpl.<init>(CLI.java:658)
> at hudson.cli.CLI.plainHttpConnection(CLI.java:684)
> at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:612)
> at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:426)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further troubleshooting  I found the issue to be linked to reverse-proxy .

“The HTTP(S) connection mode of the CLI in Jenkins 2.54 and newer does not work correctly behind an Apache HTTP reverse proxy server using mod_proxy. Workarounds include using a different reverse proxy such as Nginx or HAProxy, or using the SSH connection mode where possible.”
I used ssh instead .

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47279